# Негласное присутствие данных (с NA) в data.frame

Tags: r

После стандартной процедуры очистки от `missing data (na.omit())` получаю невозможность добавить новые переменные к `data.frame`. Выдаётся ошибка несовпадения длины. Т.е., несмотря на удаление этих строк из набора, они негласно присутствуют в `data.frame`, при этом размерность фрейма после удаления составляет 855, а новая добавляемая переменная имеет длину 970 (как в первоначальном наборе данных).

Есть ли простой выход из положения?

Comment: Попробуйте `tidyr::drop_na()`  
А вообще не помешает reproducible example

Answer (score 1):

По приведенному описанию все как раз наоборот. После выполнения na.omit данные НЕ присутствуют в наборе - изначально было 970, сколько-то там удалено, осталось 855, а вы пытаетесь к ним присоединить вектор длиной 970. Понятно, что будет несовпадание длин.
Выход - 
Сначала добавляем новый столбец, потом проводим na.omit.

Comment: В том и вопрос. Изначальный размер data.frame - 970. По идее, после удаления строк с NA, размер должен был сократиться до 855, но новый прибавляемый вектор автоматически получает длину изначального data.frame. Плюс, некоторые функции (например dataEllipse()) ругаются на присутствие NA.

Comment: Или я чего-то не понимаю, или?  Что значит "новый вектор автоматически получает длину???".                                        dataset<-na.omit(dataset)
dataset
dataset<-cbind(dataset,c(rep(1,nrow(dataset))))